What kind of plant is this? (looks like periwinkle)
Found this flowering plant near my house in Pennsylvania, USA. What kind of plant is it?
I really like it because it is keeping out the weeds. I think the previous owners had planted it.
It looks like there might be some mint to the left but I am interested in the flowering plant.
If I had to take a guess I think it is periwinkle.
I was hoping to plant more of it to keep weeds out.


You're correct, it's periwinkle.

Common periwinkle is a low-growing mat-forming, vine-like perennial nonwoody plant with green, shiny, smooth stems that are woody at the base. It spreads by underground runners or by its vine-like stems that take root at the nodes. It is not native to North America and has proven to be invasive in several states. Planting it is not recommended.


The leaves are opposite, simple, evergreen, ½–1½ inches long, ½–¾ inch wide, egg-shaped to equally rounded toward the ends, the tip blunt to pointed, the base rounded or heart-shaped, the margin lacking teeth; upper surface dark green, shiny, smooth, the central vein light green; the lower surface paler, smooth; leaves at the end of twigs often in clusters of 3 or 4, the leaf stalk ½–1¼ inches long, exuding a milky sap when broken.

That little plant with serrated leaf edges is what we called "Indian Strawberries" years ago, now better called mock or false strawberry.

I've left a message in The Biosphere but I don't think you will receive a notification because the room has been inactive for so long.
